# Could not load file or assembly '__App_Code' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, .net-4.0

> Could not load file or assembly '__App_Code' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have just converted my Website project to Web Application project, but am unable to run the web site either through IIS or through Visual Studio's development server as well, although it is successfully built...

Same error is prompted in both the cases. Can anybody help me on this?

I have tried renaming my App_Code folder to 'CodeFiles' just to check out, but the problem persists. I tried emptying the Temporary Internet Files folder as well, but to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with [Aamir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30341/aamir)'s help. It was quite obvious. The entry was in the `csproj` file for __App_Code. Removing that entry worked...